# Merge trying to join a table to itself

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a Story model and a Tag model, which has_and_belongs_to_many each other. Tags have a field called adult, which indicates that any story that has that tag contains adult content. Story has a field called adult_override, which indicates that it has adult content even if none of its tags are adult. I have the following function, which takes an ActiveRecord::Relation representing a set of stories and filters it to include only adult stories (this is a method of the Story class):

```
def self.only_adult(story_set)
  story_set.left_outer_joins(:tags)
           .distinct
           .where("stories.adult_override = true OR tags.adult = true")
end
```

I also have a function that is supposed to take a given set of stories (an ActiveRecord::Relation) and find the most common tags in that set (this is a method of the Tag class):

```
def self.most_common(story_set, num = 10)
  joins(:stories).merge(story_set)
                 .select("tags.*, COUNT(*) AS cnt")
                 .group("tags.name")
                 .reorder("cnt DESC")
                 .limit(num)
end
```

(name is the primary key of the tags table)

These methods both work fine on their own, but when I try to call most_common on a relation that's already been filtered by only_adult, I get the following error:

> Can't join 'Tag' to association named 'tags'; perhaps you misspelled
>   it?

How do I get most_common to work even if the tags table is already referenced in the story_set it's being passed?

Edit: the SQL generated by Tag.joins(stories) is:

> SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "stories_tags" ON
>   "stories_tags"."name" = "tags"."name" INNER JOIN "stories" ON
>   "stories"."id" = "stories_tags"."story_id"

and the SQL generated by only_adult is, in one example:

> SELECT DISTINCT "stories".* FROM "stories" LEFT OUTER JOIN
>   "stories_tags" ON "stories_tags"."story_id" = "stories"."id" LEFT
>   OUTER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."name" = "stories_tags"."name" WHERE
>   (true) AND (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM characters_stories INNER JOIN
>   characters ON characters_stories.character_id = characters.id WHERE
>   (characters_stories.story_id = stories.id) AND (LOWER(characters.name)
>   SIMILAR TO 'doc%'))) AND (stories.adult_override = true OR tags.adult
>   = true) ORDER BY "stories"."author" ASC

The problem occurs when these two relationships are merged.

Comment: could you include the sql generated ?

Comment: Okay, I've added that to the main post.

Comment: `Can't join 'Tag' to association named 'tags'; perhaps you misspelled it?` you are joining `tags` table with a table that is just the join between `tags` and `stories`(it is just a table including the id of tags and the respective story id). If you really need those data check out a `full outer join` on this guide https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp, test their exercise, but I don't believe that you need that. I believe you should break your scopes does accordingly to the use you need to do

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out how to get this working properly, so I'll add my solution in case anyone else has a similar problem. I replaced the body of most_common with (editing a bit for simplicity):

```
  rflct = reflect_on_association(:stories)
  join_table = rflct.join_table
  join_sql = "INNER JOIN #{join_table} AS jt ON " +
             "jt.#{rflct.foreign_key} = " +
             "answer.name}"
  processed_set = story_set.where("stories.id = jt.#{rflct.association_foreign_key}")

  self.select('answer.*, COUNT(*) as cnt')
      .from("tags AS answer")
      .joins(join_sql)
      .where("EXISTS (#{processed_set.to_sql})")
      .group("answer.tags")
      .reorder('cnt DESC')
      .limit(num)
```

I'm not entirely happy with this -- I feel like there's probably a more elegant way to accomplish this -- but it does work.